# Free sketching on LibreOffice Draw

Tags: linux, linux-mint, libreoffice

I have a drawing Graphical Board and am trying to draw in LibreOffice Draw using it.
The only options I can find are to insert images, draw shapes and insert text.
Is there a simple "free (drawing/sketching)" option? (i.e like drawing on paper)

Note: If there is no option to do in LibreOffice Draw, I am ok with other software suggestions, but the software needs to support multiple pages (something that InkSpace for example dosen't). I am coming from Windows and I am looking for an equivalent to Inkodo, which is what I used there.

(I have Linux Mint)

Thanks!

Comment: Does a [freeform line](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/02/01140000.html) do what you want?

Comment: @JimK I dont see this option within the drawing tools in LibreOffice Draw. Where can I find it "GUI wise"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a picture of the freeform line tool.

[image: freeform line tool in LibreOffice Draw]

Also answered at https://superuser.com/questions/1352587/how-do-you-draw-freehand-like-a-pencil-tool-in-libreoffice-draw.